# awk: function asorti never defined

Tags: bash, awk, ubuntu-16.04

I'm wrting awk program and program needs to sort the "associative array"

```
{
    subj[$1]++  
}
END{

    n=asorti(subj, sorted)
    for(k=1;k<=n;k++)
    {
        print(k" "sorted[k])
    }
}
```

while exceuting with below cmd

```
$ awk -f prg.awk "subjects"
```

giving below error:

awk: function asorti never defined

[inputfile]

```
Phy
Math
Math
Science
Bio
Phy
```

Operating system: ubuntu 16.04

Excepted o/p

```
Bio 1
Math 2
Phy 2
Science 1
```

Comment: And which awk are you using?

Comment: @JamesBrown Awk 4.1.3

Comment: Don't use `print(foo" "bar)`. `print` is an operator in Awk, not a function. Parens are not required. You can give it multiple arguments separated by commas. Their values are printed with the `OFS` (output field separator) between them, which is a single space by default, and with  `ORS` (output record separator) at the end, newline by default.  So, `print k, sorted[k]` is idiomatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Gnu awk you can set the `for` scanning order with `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]`:

```
$ cat > foo.awk
{
    a[$1]++
} 
END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"  # scanning in index ascending order
    for(i in a)                           # for here uses above defined order
        print i,a[i]
}
Bio 1
Math 2
Phy 2
Science 1
```

https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html

Comment: Thanks. Yes tried. Its coming. But how can I achieve my given o/p. Frequency of subject is not coming.

Comment: That's probably because your code is still referring to the `sorted` array, which does not exist. That array was supposed to be produced by `asorti`.

Comment: @SeeTheC if the awk you are running doesn't have `asorti()` then it's not GNU awk and so certainly doesn't have `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` so if you are getting output in the order you expected, it's pure coincidence of hashing order for this input set matching your desired order and you haven't actually solved your problem which is that the awk you were running that told you asorti() is undefined was not GNU awk, all you've done is hide the problem (since populating an unused array named PROCINFO will not produce an error message).

Comment: It's customary to comment when downvoting.